# How to create chart lists from a mongo collection elements in Meteor

Tags: meteor, chart.js

I have a hard coded (but working) Meteor chart that includes

```
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
```

and

```
data: [random(), random(), random(), random(), random(), random(), random()]
```

Now, I want to generate the labels and data lists from a mongo collection.

The mongo collection looks like

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.stutterRatings.find()
{ "_id" : "qokM4aGwJH9ppXDBL", "rating" : "4", "date" : ISODate("2015-09-24T10:02:50.945Z") }
{ "_id" : "nC4ut3xzmu2fHH93w", "rating" : "3", "date" : ISODate("2015-09-24T10:02:56.716Z") }
{ "_id" : "wathoLgoN5HH8K4Dx", "rating" : "9", "date" : ISODate("2015-09-24T10:10:09.768Z") }
{ "_id" : "24ndAsJQQv6Akbdr5", "rating" : "10", "date" : ISODate("2015-09-24T10:33:19.044Z") }
```

The `date` values will be used as labels and the `rating` values will be used as data. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) fetch the data on the client:

```
var dataset = Data.find({<--whatever-query-you-need-->},{fields: {labels:1, rating:1}}).fetch()
```

2) map the field to what you need:

```
var labels = dataset.map(function(d) { return d.label; }
var data = dataset.map(function(d) {return d.rating; }
```

if you use d3js you may be able to just pass the data to the enter function and then the mapping function to each axis.

Comment: You answer makes sense to me and I have tried to implement it.  However, I cannot understand why the following is happening.  If I run the 'var dataset ...' statement in the browser's console the dataset variable contains data but... if I run it from the meteor pages .js file it returns an empty list.  That is, console.log(StutterRatings.find().fetch()); returns []

Comment: are you publishing the dataset?

Comment: you need to do: Meteor.publish('data',function(){return Data.find({}...) on the server, and then Meteor.subscribe('data'); on the client.

Comment: to debug and for a good view of everything going ot the client, try the MeteorToys package and press CTRL+M to get the HUD of your data

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but I am still using autopublish and doing what you said did not seem to make a difference.  I have accepted your original answer as it did solve the original issue

Comment: not sure what is not working for you, but re-reading your post and comments, it seems like you problem may be with the waiting for the data to be published, which would explain why in the JS file it's not there yet but on the console it has arrived. 
What router do you use? Do you have a subscribe or waitOn parameter there (assuming you use Iron-router)? Not sure this is the problem but that may be some direction.

Comment: I am using iron:router and do not subscribe (as I am still using insecure and autopublish) nor use waitOn.  The problem has sort of gone away as I now ask the user to select a particular user before showing my chart.  However, I think your waitOn theory will be correct as on a couple of intermittent occasions the JS did show values